# How can I serve individual static text files with the same name from the webroot for each multisite instance?

Tags: 8, multi-sites

I use Drupal 8 and I want serve statics files in each multiple sites with Nginx.

I've a site at `web/sites/site_1/` and a site at `web/sites/site_2/`.

I want serve *ads.txt* or *robots.txt* for each sites with different content.

I can add directory in `site_1/statics/` with files and serve this files at root with Nginx but I don't know how I can to do this.

Is it possible to do this with Nginx? Or is there some other way?

Answer (score 0):

It maybe is possible with Nginx but Nginx config is off-topic. Please have a look at the [RobotsTxt](https://www.drupal.org/project/robotstxt) module instead. The RobotsTxt module simply provides you a /robots.txt route that behaves just like a normal robots.txt file with the difference that you can configure the content of it from the back-end **per site**. You only need to pay attention that you deleted the physical robots.txt file to let the RobotsTxt module do its work.

> Use this module when you are running multiple Drupal sites from a
>   single code base (multisite) and you need a different robots.txt file
>   for each one. This module generates the robots.txt file dynamically
>   and gives you the chance to edit it, on a per-site basis, from the web
>   UI.
>
> **Note:** You must delete or rename the robots.txt file in the root of your Drupal installation for this module to display its own robots.txt
>   file(s).

This solves your robots.txt problem. The ads.txt needs to be solved the same way. You need to create a custom module that does just the same as the RobotsTxt module for the /ads.txt route. With an admin settings form to store its content.